# Simple queue system not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to implement a simple yet effective queue system to my NodeJS Express API, at the moment I've got the following inside my `app.get` request:

```
createOrder(req, res).catch(function ignore() {});
return res.send(functions.success_response({
    'MESSAGE': 'Order Received!'
}));
```

This `createOrder` function has the following:

```
let params = await parser.parseStringPromise(req.body.parameters);

state.device_imei = params.PARAMETERS.IMEI;

while(queue.length >= 10) {
    console.log('Current Queue Length: ' + queue.length + ', IMEI: ' + state.device_imei + ' waiting...');
}

queue.push(state.device_imei);

//some more code logic here.....

queue.splice(queue.indexOf(state.device_imei), 1 );
```

My `queue` variable is just a simple global scope `let queue = [];`

The issue I appear to be having is that my queue doesn't seem to decrease? and is forever stuck at the `while()`?

Also, how could I change the `while` so it does the check every 1 second rather than instantly recurring?

Comment: You're not changing the `queue` in the `while`, hence this is equal to `while(true) { ... }`. And because nodejs is single-threaded the process is not able to do anything other which could remove something from the queue.

Comment: currently in the while loop I don't see your queue decreases, decreasing is done outside, so when your queue arrives to +10 your code will be stuck there forever.

Comment: @F.bernal If I send 50 GET requests, that's 50 functions right? so if the first 10 bypass the `while` loop then surely it'd decrease it?

Comment: @Curtis If you send 50 GET request, the request 11 makes your code be stuck.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you are not changing the `queue` array in the body of your `while` function.

Here is a working example of what you want to achieve, although I would suggest you look into open source alternatives.

```js
const queueState = {
  processing: false,
  items: [],
};

function processQueue() {
  if (queueState.processing) {
    return;
  }
  // Lock the queue whilst the current items are being processed
  queueState.processing = true;

  // Process items from back of queue to front
  for (let i = queueState.items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // Do whatever you need to do with each queue item
    console.log(queueState.items[i]);
    // Remove item from queue
    queueState.items.splice(i, 1);
  }

  // Release the queue for future items to be processed
  queueState.processing = false;
}

// Start processing the queue immediately
processQueue();
// Process the queue every second (if it's not already processing)
setInterval(processQueue, 1000);

// Add some items to the queue
queueState.items.push(1);
queueState.items.push(2);
queueState.items.push(3);

// Add some more items to the queue in the future
setTimeout(() => {
  queueState.items.push(4);
  queueState.items.push(5);
}, 1500);
```